# Адаптивной верстка не подстраивается под ширину экрана

Tags: html, css, responsive

Есть [сайт](http://denis-lev.tk/test5).

Верстка адаптивная, но на некоторых устройствах есть такая [проблема](http://joxi.ru/zAN0QK5H8dgGm9): верстка не подстраивается почему-то под доступную ширину экрана.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в тег `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: У ответу xaja. Вот к [теме viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Viewport) Тут много полезной, рускоязычной инфорации, даже статья етсь о viewport.

Answer (score -1):

Почитай про viewport.Есть книга Итан Маркотт
"Отзывчивый веб-дизайн"